# Date Validation using datepicker in YII

Tags: php, jquery, yii, datepicker

I want to validate my date field from datepicker such that it should not allow any date before today.

This is what I have in my YII-

Model:

```
protected function beforeSave()
{
$this->edate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->edate));
return TRUE;
}

protected function afterFind()
{
$this->edate=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($this->edate));
return TRUE;
}

public function rules()
{
array('edate', 'safe'),
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Date is getting stored in db in correct way, but I want to validate the date field which does not allow any date before today's date.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to yii,But still try using `compare` validator

```
public function rules(){
  return array(
     array('edate','compare','compareValue'=>date('Y-m-d'),'operator'=>'>=', 'allowEmpty'=>false),
  );
}
```

Comment: Would that compare mean with "todays" date?

Comment: I have my datepicker in d-m-Y format.
If I edit your given code as date(d-m-Y), it is not working. How do I change it now?

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the datepicker such a way that it will not allow the user to select the days before the current day. This can be done by setting like

```
 datepicker({
            minDate: 0,//0th days from presnt day will be selectable
            dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
             ...
      });
```

or compare the both using the following logic

```
 $date = "2004-02-29"; 
 $unix_date = strtotime ($date); 

 if ($unix_date < time() ) { echo "date is before"; } 
 else { echo "date is after"; }
```

This [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/168/create-your-own-validation-rule/) wiil help you in writing your own validation rule.